# python for-loop to remove duplication in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

hi everyone this is my code to remove repeated items in a list of numbers:

```
numbers=[5,2,2,2,2,2,34,5,46,78,65,34,78,34,3,2,47,5,8,76]
for item in numbers:
        if numbers.count(item)>1:
                 numbers.remove(item)
print(numbers)
```

and the result is this:
[2, 2, 46, 65, 78, 34, 3, 2, 47, 5, 8, 76]

still has repeated items. but if i change the code in this way:
for item in numbers[ : ]
it would work and the result is:
[46, 65, 78, 34, 3, 2, 47, 5, 8, 76]

```
what s the difference?
```

Comment: In your loop you're modifying a list which you are iterating over (bad). `a[:]` causes a list to be copied into a new object.

Comment: When the iteration gets to index two and you decide to remove that item, *in* the list what **was** at index 3 is **now** at index two; the iteration continues with the next index (3) which has the item that *used-to-be* at index four - an item got skipped and is never processed. Using a copy for iteration prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove items from a list while you're iterating it! That's very dangerous and can return weird results, as you can see. Instead, you can use this approach:

```
c = set()
unique_numbers = []
for n in numbers:
    if n not in c:
        unique_numbers.append(n)
        c.add(n)
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> unique_numbers
[5, 2, 34, 46, 78, 65, 3, 47, 8, 76]
```

If the order of the numbers does not matter then you can use this approach:

```
unique_numbers = list(set(numbers))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. of coures this is the corrrect way to do that. but i d like to know how it was executed in that way.